# In-cell Validation Drop-down list - widen

Tags: microsoft-excel, data-validation

I have quite a few cells with Data Validation with options in the list that are long strings. Short of widening the column, is there any way to widen the drop-down list so that the user can see the options?

I could possibly use the Design Toolbox, but I'd rather keep it simple.

I *cannot* use VBA for this; there already exist solution using VBA.

Comment: The solution can't use VBA?

Comment: I'd rather not, due to draconian anti-virus/malware restrictions. Just wondering if it could be done easily, via options somewhere.

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is 'No'.  The Data Validation feature can be used as a quick-and-dirty replacement for a genuine drop-down/combobox, but it is limited in the amount of features and options.

Answer (score 0):

Merge some adjacent cells.